# average and for in Cognos Analytics

Tags: cognos-bi

Presently I'm using the following code to obtain specific average based on conditions -

```
round(average( [Duration] for [P_CODE], [STEP_TYPE]='Electronics Processing'),2)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when we run this code as a part of our environment. I have to find a way to do the same to get the duration's average based on this `STEP_TYPE` instead of using the "for" in the average for the specific `STEP_TYPE`.

This Average is getting populated within a List shown below. 
Thanks

Comment: So, since I used the for clause within the Average is giving us an error, I'm trying to use if and else or case statement to see if I can pull the same information without using the "For"

Comment: So, the following works great!! round(average( [Duration] for [P_CODE], [STEP_TYPE]='Electronics Processing'),2) and shows the value even when I drop it to a Singleton ---> Table Cell for Electronics Processing Step type. But the use of Case like below, is not returning, case
when  [STEP_TYPE] in ('Electronic Processing')  then
round((average(_days_between([V_C_C],[V_C_O]) for [P_CODE])),2)
else
0
end IT FAILS. I have an attachment I can show but not sure how to send attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
round(
     average (
          CASE 
          WHEN [STEP_TYPE] = 'Electronics Processing' THEN [Duration] 
          ELSE null 
          END
     for [P_CODE])
,2)
```

Nulls are excluded from aggregates such as count() and average().

Comment: Yes, this answered my question. Thank you so much!